# CUDA 7.5 on 16.06 lts - cudaErrorDeviceUnavailable

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, cuda

I am trying to run CUDA 7.5 toolkit in an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS environment and have gotten very close to having the full capabilities. I can run the deviceQuerry as shown below, but I can not run certain samples as is also shown below (nbody).

I was having an issue with the libGLU.so library and associated files but I was able to get past those errors... it is now that I am having no luck solving the error listed below...

Do you know what might be the problem and what I could try to fix this?

```
___@___:/usr/local/cuda/samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery$ ./deviceQuery
./deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "Quadro K620"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          8.0 / 7.5
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    5.0
  Total amount of global memory:                 1993 MBytes (2090008576 bytes)
  ( 3) Multiprocessors, (128) CUDA Cores/MP:     384 CUDA Cores
  GPU Max Clock rate:                            1124 MHz (1.12 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             900 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              128-bit
  L2 Cache Size:                                 2097152 bytes
  Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(65536), 2D=(65536, 65536), 3D=(4096, 4096, 4096)
  Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(16384), 2048 layers
  Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(16384, 16384), 2048 layers
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 65536
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  2048
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
  Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (2147483647, 65535, 65535)
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 1 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     Yes
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Device PCI Domain ID / Bus ID / location ID:   0 / 1 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 8.0, CUDA Runtime Version = 7.5, NumDevs = 1, Device0 = Quadro K620
Result = PASS



___@___:/usr/local/cuda/samples/5_Simulations/nbody$ ./nbody
Run "nbody -benchmark [-numbodies=<numBodies>]" to measure performance.
    -fullscreen       (run n-body simulation in fullscreen mode)
    -fp64             (use double precision floating point values for simulation)
    -hostmem          (stores simulation data in host memory)
    -benchmark        (run benchmark to measure performance) 
    -numbodies=<N>    (number of bodies (>= 1) to run in simulation) 
    -device=<d>       (where d=0,1,2.... for the CUDA device to use)
    -numdevices=<i>   (where i=(number of CUDA devices > 0) to use for simulation)
    -compare          (compares simulation results running once on the default GPU and once on the CPU)
    -cpu              (run n-body simulation on the CPU)
    -tipsy=<file.bin> (load a tipsy model file for simulation)

NOTE: The CUDA Samples are not meant for performance measurements. Results may vary when GPU Boost is enabled.

> Windowed mode
> Simulation data stored in video memory
> Single precision floating point simulation
> 1 Devices used for simulation
> Compute 5.0 CUDA device: [Quadro K620]
CUDA error at bodysystemcuda_impl.h:160 code=46(cudaErrorDevicesUnavailable) "cudaEventCreate(&m_deviceData[0].event)"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42428296/2073255